# Is it okay to do another process inside the filter method in java 8 streams

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I know how to filter a collection based on condition and collect. I am wondering is it okay to do another process inside the filter.

```
List<SupplementaryCustomer> supplementaryCustomersWithMoreThan100Points = new ArrayList<>();
List<Customer> customersWithMoreThan100Points = customers
  .stream()
  .filter(c -> {
     boolean isOkay = c.getPoints() > 100;
     if(isOkay && (c.isSupplementaryCustomer())){
       SupplementaryCustomer.add(c);
     }
     return isOkay;
   })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

let's say that **customers** object has all types of customers. and i needed to get supplementary customers With MoreThan 100 Points and customers With More Than 100 Points. i am doing something like this in my codebase. is it okay to do something like this?

Comment: No for some reasons. 1- is killing readability 2- has side effects

Answer (score 1):

Streams should be side effect free except for terminal operations that are intended for side-effects (foreach). What you're doing is violating this paradigm. The cost of streaming the resulting list again and then filtering by your other critera for adding to the other list is neglible if there aren't millions of items in your list and even then I'd advocate against violating languager paradigms to gain a small performance boost.

```
List<Customer> customersWithMoreThan100Points = customers
  .stream()
  .filter(c -> c.getPoints() > 100)
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); 

List<SupplementaryCustomer> supplementaryCustomersWithMoreThan100Points = customersWithMoreThan100Points
    .stream()
    .filter(c -> c.isSupplementaryCustomer())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's easier to read, less complex, more compliant to the intent of Streams and I doubt you'll find a noticeable (or even measurable) perfomance loss in any typical use case.

Comment: Oh, yes. Just the object `SupplementaryCustomer` collection might be worth detailing.

Comment: Yes, but that's up to OP, I don't know anything about this except for what OP posted...

Comment: Not in all cases. For example, someList.stream.forEach() can have side effects. map, filter etc shouldn't.

Comment: @SamwellTarly thanks, added that one but foreach is a terminal operation that's intended for side.effects while filter isn't.

Comment: @Nicktar there are many scenarios i had to think for using the above code.
let's say that there can be situations each customer may have 5 to 300 supplementary customers. supplementary customer object is inside the customer object. when the time we query customers from a table we query the whole customers. (query by supplementary customers).

Comment: at the same time, i have to consider about the performance of this.

Comment: If you have to consider the performance, you need to have a benchmark to meet. If you have a benchmark to meet you can test if this nanoseconds will be to much. if they are to much, you're in trouble anyway. If you can answer no to any of these, it's just premature optimization.